# What is this plant with oval leaflets in a compound leaf?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

I have this plant growing in my garden and I am unable to guess what plant it is.

What is it?

Comment: You're not giving much to go on. Can you take more photographs? These are too blurry to tell whether or not the edges of the leaves are toothed, and what the veins look like. How large is it? Is it a woody shrub or tree, or a vine, or is it herbaceous? Is it an ornamental planted in your garden, or did it just show up spontaneously, and if so, is it weedy? What do the flowers and fruit look like? Where in the world are you? Do you know if this plant is native to where you live?

Comment: Until we know more all I can say is that it looks like a member of the legume family.

Comment: I was thinking legume, too.

Comment: More photos of the actual plant growing, showing overall shape and growth habit would also be useful, and knowing where you are, as Steve K asks

Comment: @mehek: If you ever return to this, please add the information that other respondents have asked for so we can take it off hold and hopefully provide you with an answer. Thanks.